# Require understanding regarding the concept of restricted estimators

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics, optimization

I was reading *"The Elements of Statistical Learning
Book by Jerome H. Friedman, Robert Tibshirani, and Trevor Hastie"* where I encountered the following:

[image]

The part tells us that the RSS criterion will lead us to infinitely many solutions and in order to obtain a unique solution we need to put some restrictions on the RSS criterion.

The book further discusses the following methods to impose such restrictions.

- **Roughness penalty**
- **Kernel methods**
- **Basis Functions and Dictionary Methods**

I very specifically want to understand:

- These methods with some simple examples
- The intuition behind each of these methods
- Please suggest an appropriate source for better understanding

Thank you!

Comment: You have to explain better what you do not understand. Dumping three pages of a book on a post does not help.